# How to compute $i^i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

My question is a bit straightforward. How can I solve $i^i$? Do I have to work it out based on polar form of complex number? Even that doesn't seem to help!!

Comment: If you start with the definition of exponentiation, it's not too difficult: $$i^i = e^{i \log i}$$ where $\log$ refers to whatever branch of the logarithm you're using at the moment.

Comment: $i=e^{\frac\pi2i}$ so $i^i=e^{\frac\pi2i\cdot i}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$i^i = e^{\pi /2 \cdot i \cdot i} = e^ {-\pi/2}$

Answer (score 2):

$i^i=e^{i \, log \,i}=exp\left(i\left(ln(1)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)=\cdots$